# Cant write string in new line

Tags: java, io

I cant write string in file in new line, although i add "\n" to the end of string

```
public void writeEquation(String fileName, String expr) {     
        File aFile = new File(fileName);
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(aFile, true);
            BufferedWriter buffered = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            buffered.write(expr+"\n");
            buffered.flush();
            buffered.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Are you on Windows or on UNIX?

Comment: Try opening the file using a proper text editor like Notepad++ instead of plain Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use the [newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) method provided by the `BufferedWriter` class?

> Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character.

In your code, change:

```
 buffered.write(expr+"\n");
```

to :

```
 buffered.write(expr);
 buffered.newLine();
```

Later edit: Also I am not sure where you want the new line, but if you want to make sure that your `expr` string gets added **on a new line at the end of a file**, then call the method before calling `buffered.write(expr)` like:

```
buffered.newLine();
buffered.write(expr);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `BufferedWriter.newLine()` method of `BufferedWriter`. This will help in tiding over the quirks dependent on OS

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
buffered.write("\n"+expr);
```

When you do expr+"\n" you are getting newline after your string.